# Yii Page Variation

Tags: php, yii, url-routing

I have a website that needs to have a variation of pages.

For example:

```
website.com/variation1/page1
website.com/variation2/page1
website.com/variation3/page1
```

All of which has the same DB and has the same function. The only difference is that these variations differs in page template ie. Header, Footer, Content, etc. This is for the purpose of analyzing page visits.

With that, what is the best way to do this? In Yii, there is a common layout used so header/footer depends on the layout. In this case, the header/footer should be specific to each page so the user can just modify the header/footer/content of a specific page without affecting other pages.

So, again what is the best approach for this?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I think I know what I'm looking for here:
Is there a way to override/add from a layout the header in a view file?

Comment: The controller has a `layout` property, and it looks for a file in `/protected/views/layouts`. You can modify this in an action.

Comment: @Örs thank you for that. However, I already know that, what I am specifically looking for is a way to override what is on the layout header. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out a possible solution to approach page variations.

Under my view directory I created a directory `varation` which contains the pages i.e.

```
/view/variation/1/page1.php
/view/variation/2/page1.php
```

So when I want to render the varations I'll call each in the controller with parameters included.

Ex. `$this->render('variation/1/page1')` somewhat.

And in each page if you want to use a specific header info you may use

Register Meta Tag

Register Script File / Script

Register CSS File / CSS

Let me know if there are better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Create Three different layouts say variation1.php, variation2.php, variation3.php, then based on the action(website.com/variation/pageone) or the parameter(website.com/variation/page/1) change the layout(in action).

Comment: I think this is a good idea. I'll try this as well. However the problem is when the content is changed the contents to other variations are changed as well. Is it not?